# How can I receive and block uninstalling app in android

Tags: uninstallation, android

How can I receive and block uninstalling app in android? I've tested receiver on IntentFilter with *android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED* and *android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED* actions and receiver runs when some app has been **fully unnistalled**. I want to catch this action **before** user prompt.
I know it is possible, because it works perfectly in AVAST Mobile Security app for android.

Comment: I would be surprised if that is possible because then you could prevent your own app from being uninstalled, or not?

Comment: yes, I could. but I can force stop this AVAST app and then it doesn't work of course. but I don't know how to make something like this yet.